# Get JSON data with Django

Tags: python, json, django

I am playing around with GeoIP2 and requested the following in **my view**.

```
g = GeoIP2()
city = g.city('google.com')
tests = Test.objects.all()

args = { 'tests': tests }

return render(request, 'app/home.html', args)
```

I receive a **JSON response** with a bunch of data, I am interested in "city" for example.

```
{'city': None, 'continent_code': 'NA', 'continent_name': 'North America', 'country_code': 'US',     'country_name': 'United States', 'dma_code': None, 'latitude': 37.751, 'longitude': -97.822, 'postal_code': None, 'region': None, 'time_zone': 'America/Chicago'}
```

**My model**

```
# Create your models here.
class Test(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(default='', max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.browser_family
```

Despite some googling and Youtube videos I am not quite sure how I should grab for example "city" out of the JSON response. I looked at previous threads here but not quite sure it can be applied here, seems like other threads were for more sophisticated stuff.

Any suggestions out there?

**SOLVED**
city = g.city('google.com')
json = city['city']

Comment: city is json response? --> ```city['city']```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab/assign it as follows:

city = JSON_response(‘city‘)

What happens here:

You assign the `value` of the `key` "city" of your `JSON_reponse` to the `variable` "city.

In your example `city` will be `None`

Comment: Could  you elaborate? I already assigned the variable city the following: g.city('google.com'). Should I assign a new value after that to the same city variable? Sorry for the beginner questions.

Comment: Your JSON reponse states `'city': None`. If you now want to assign `None` to the variable `city` you use the formula given above in my answer. Please accept answer if sufficient.

Comment: Okay city = g.city('google.com') retrieves the JSON, should I make another variable with the same name below it? city = JSON_response('city')? It's just the structure I'm confused about. If I only use city = JSON_response('city') I have no variable that collects the JSON in the first place.

Comment: define a variable to grab the JSON response as an object and then slice the contained information into other variables as needed, yes.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, so the journey continues.